# How to remove SharePoint logo from Highlighted Content Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, highlighted-content-web-part

Is there a way to please remove the sharepoint logo has highlighted in the below image below?

[image]

Comment: Are you showing "pages" in this web part? Unfortunately, we cannot customize the UI/functionality of SharePoint default web parts - You can only change the web part settings available by default and see if those satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Yes i'm showing tha pages. Is this why it has the icon?